# std.algorithm.remove() duplicating array items?

Tags: arrays, indexing, slice, d, phobos

I have an array that I need to remove items from, by index. It for some reason duplicates other items in the array to take the removed item's place. Here is an example of the issue.

```
import std.stdio: writeln;
import std.algorithm: remove;

void main() {
    string[string] assocArray = [
        "firstvalue": "Number 1",
        "secondvalue": "Number 2",
        "thirdvalue": "Number 3",
        "fourthvalue": "Number 4",
        "fifthvalue": "Number 5",
        "sixthvalue": "Number 6",
    ];

    string[] assocArrayKeys = assocArray.keys(); // I know these aren't in the same order as the literal.

    writeln(assocArrayKeys);
    // ["thirdvalue", "fourthvalue", "fifthvalue", "sixthvalue", "firstvalue", "secondvalue"]

    assocArrayKeys.remove(0);
    assocArrayKeys.remove(5);

    writeln(assocArrayKeys);
    // ["fourthvalue", "fifthvalue", "sixthvalue", "firstvalue", "secondvalue", "secondvalue"]
    // It did remove them, but there are now two "secondvalue"s.
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was somewhat of a silly question. Someone pointed out that in the documentation, it says that it has to be reassigned to itself.

> Note that remove does not change the length of the original range directly; instead, it returns the shortened range. If its return value is not assigned to the original range, the original range will retain its original length, though its contents will have changed.

Source: https://dlang.org/library/std/algorithm/mutation/remove.html

The solution is as follows:

```
assocArraykeys = assocArrayKeys.remove(0);
assocArrayKeys = assocArrayKeys.remove(5);
```

This seems a little silly and unintuitive to me though because it is in `std.algorithm.mutation`. Keyword: *mutation*.